# Find how much something as reduced by in %

Tags: percentile

I'm using Huffman encoding to perform an encoding on a string, soon I'll move it be used on compressing images.

I've got the length of the string: **x**
I've got the length of the encode string: **y**

I want to know in a percentage how much smaller **y** is than **x**. So I can say I've shrunk the input string by **%**

I'm probably making it harder than it actually is in my head, which is why I got a mind block.

How do you work that? I presume its really really easy! Simple maths is always the hardest :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input string is shrunk by $$\frac{x-y}{x}\times 100$$ percent.

Comment: Perfect, I knew it was something easy, just sucks when your brain goes dead!